# Source Control for Self-Managed Project

Tags: c#, version-control

What source control would be recommended to use for a self-managed project? It's a C# WPF project on Visual Studio 2010.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Mercurial](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/) with it's, probably, best Windows Desktop client [TortoiseHG](http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.io/). 
If you would like online repository, you can use [GoogleCode](http://code.google.com/). For local, fast changes, or some experimental stuff you can use a local one, provided by Mercurial itself, like all standard [Distributed revision control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_revision_control) system.

If you want good information on the management of Mercurial in general and HG in like a client, you can have look on excelent article from Joel Spolsky:

[Hg Init: a Mercurial tutorial](http://hginit.com/)

There are also other alteranatives, like [Git](http://git-scm.com/), for example, but honestly, *I* find Mercurial much easier to manage and understand and much more suitable for simple personal projects than Git or any other. It perfectly combines, in my opinion, the power of distributed system (with probably less functionality than Git offers, but do you **really** need all of that functionality??) and simplicity of control, which is the main point on my opinion.

Answer (score 2):

If you do not want to set up your own repo, you may use [bitbucket.org](http://bitbucket.org).

It is free for private commercial repos and works with bot git and Mercurial.

Answer (score 0):

Personally ? I'd use git / tortoisegit.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend Team Foundation Service. It's still in preview and it is completely free.

You can subscribe at http://tfspreview.com

It integrates nicely with Visual Studio. You dont't have to install anything or worry about backups.

Answer (score 0):

[AnjhSVN](http://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/) (VS Plugin), using [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.net/). You will also need an [SVN Server](http://www.visualsvn.com/server/licensing/). All three are free.